# Extract two integers from single line and assign to separate variables

Tags: grep, variable

I'm trying to extract integers from a line that looks like this:

```
Result: 23/200
```

I'd like to assign each integer (`23` and `200`) to separate variables but can't figure out how. I have gotten this far:

```
echo "Result: 23/200." | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'
```

Which gives output:

```
23
200
```

I can also pipe into `head -1` or `tail -1` to get the first or second line. However, I have been unable to figure out the right magic to extricate the two and assign them to distinct variables.

Is my only option to pipe into a file and then read from said file? That's what I'm leaning towards right now.

Comment: One way could be to assign to an array: `arr=( $(echo "..." | grep -o -E '[0-9]+') )` Just ensure IFS is non numeric.

Comment: Or in ksh/bash/zsh `read a b < <(echo "..." | grep)`. If you can change IFS at least temporarily just `IFS=:/ read x a b < <(echo "...")` or `IFS=:/ read x a b <<<$line`. If you want a pipe `something | IFS=:/ read x a b` technically works but depending on shell and options may execute the `read` in a subshell so the variable settings are immediately discarded; then you need `something | { IFS=:/ read x a b; do all things with $a $b; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you know there's no other text on the line, then

```bsh
IFS=' /' read -r result first second <<<"$line"

declare -p first second
```

outputs

```
declare -- first="23"
declare -- second="200"
```

If you don't know how much other text is on the line, then I'd use a regex:

```bsh
if [[ $line =~ ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) ]]; then
    first=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    second=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash, this works:

```
{ read aa; read bb; } < <(echo "Result: 23/200." | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
```

after which, `echo aa=$aa bb=$bb.` produces the expected result.